# How to get place type with address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=zh-tw
In this web , I can input something to know what address , type or Location I input. How can I get the type I input ? as I input "Taipei 101 starbucks" , the web will response : 110臺灣台北市信義區信義路5段7號35之一  , Location :25.033718,121.56481 , Types : cafe , establishment , food , point of interest.
How to get the Types?

```
 List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
 try {
      addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(search, 1);
 catch (IOException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 android.location.Address address = addressList.get(1);
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), 
 address.getLongitude());
```

this part can help me find the lat and lng ,but I want to find the place types

Comment: post codes you did

Comment: I only find the code that response lat and lng but can't find the place